# How to limit function calls in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, testing

I need a function limitCalls (fn, maxCalls) that takes a function fn and returns a new function that can be called no more than the number of times specified in maxCalls. Test example:

```
 it('limitCalls', () => {
const makeIncrement = () => {
  let count = 0;

  return () => {
    count += 1;
    return count;
  };
};

const limitedIncrementA = limitCalls(makeIncrement(), 3);

expect(limitedIncrementA()).toBe(1);
expect(limitedIncrementA()).toBe(2);
expect(limitedIncrementA()).toBe(3);
expect(limitedIncrementA()).toBe(undefined);
expect(limitedIncrementA()).toBe(undefined);

const limitedIncrementB = limitCalls(makeIncrement(), 1);

expect(limitedIncrementB()).toBe(1);
expect(limitedIncrementB()).toBe(undefined);
expect(limitedIncrementB()).toBe(undefined);
```

});

I have:

```
var calls = 0;
export default function limitCalls(fn, maxCalls) {
  if (calls >= maxCalls) {
    return undefined;
  }
  calls += 1;
  return fn();
}
```

And error is limitedIncrementA is not a function. Help me please to realise it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of conditionally returning a function, always return a function that conditionally executes the `fn` callback:

```js
function limitCalls(fn, maxCalls) {
  let count = 0;
  
  return function(...args) {
    return count++ < maxCalls ? fn(...args) : undefined;
  }
}

const limited = limitCalls(console.log, 3);

limited('one');
limited('two');
limited('three');
limited('four');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, `limitedIncrementA` isn't indeed a function. See this:

```js
/* You're calling makeIncrement,
   so you're passing its return to 'limitCalls'
 */
const limitedIncrementA = limitCalls(makeIncrement(), 3);

/* Here, considering that makeIncrement exists,
   you're passing a reference to this functions,
   which can be called inside 'limitCalls'
 */
const limitedIncrementB = limitCalls(makeIncrement, 3);
```

So, supposing that `makeIncrement` returns 1, 2, 3, ..., your current code is equivalent to:

```js
limitCalls(1, 3);
```

Comment: I got it. But according to the task I can't change test code. Is there any way to make limitedIncrementA a function inside limitCalls?

Comment: You can return what you called 'fn' then, without invoking (without parenthesis) but you can also check this code with a `console.log(makeIncrement())` to see if this is actually returning a function